# How to consume a complex type returned by a WebMethod on client side using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, web-services

Iam a beginner with Webmethods and Services an I have landed in a situation here.

I have a webmethod that returns an instance of StatusViewModel class..

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static StatusViewModel GetTime1()
    {
        Debug.Write("Timer");

        StatusViewModel statusViewModel = new StatusViewModel();
        statusViewModel.Label1 = "aaa";
        statusViewModel.Label1 = "bbb";

        statusViewModel.ListBox.Add("1", "ccc");
        statusViewModel.ListBox.Add("2", "ccc");

        return DateTime.Now.ToString();

    }
```

StatusViewModel class looks like this one

```
public class StatusViewModel
    {
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string Label2 { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> ListBox { get; set; }
    }
```

How should I consume this method and set 2 labels and list-box with the data received from the method ?

Usually this is how I call webmethod

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            call1();
        });


        function OnSuccess1(result, ctrl) { $('#<%=Label2.ClientID %>').html(result); }
        function OnError1() { alert("error!"); }
        function call1() { PageMethods.GetTime1(OnSuccess1, OnError1); }
```

This works if the return type is String.

Can any one suggest any simple articles regarding this topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one, could be nice for start.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

It gives you information, rest - just google and try something by your self. It is easy and very common task.

Answer (score 0):

try converting your class to JSON. Then you can read it easily in javascript

Comment: @Fender..+1 .Thanks .. Can u suggest any article regarding how to do that ?

Comment: Bad suggestion, you should never do that manually http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: didn't know that it is done by the framework, never had this case. And whenever i used JavaScriptSerializer i did not had to do double JSON.parse...